Destructive young man shoots a cow in head and the old farmer says it's OK
I remember a scene from a movie where a destructive young man who is in the middle of some sort of journey, reaches a farm with many cows and shoots one of them in the head, just because it calm hims down. 
Then the old farmer comes close to young man and says: "It's OK son. Come and try another one." 
By the next morning, almost all the cows are dead, and the young man who is almost crying gives his gun to the farmer as a thank you.
I really loved this film, and this scene is all I remember from it. Anyone know which film this is?

When did you see it?

@Filmzy I'm not sure, probably 4 or 5 years ago.

Was it new at the time?  Trying to get a feel for when the movie may have come out.

@Filmzy sorry, I'm not really sure. it might be from any time between 1995 and 2005... and I think it was American.

I can only think of two movies, neither really match your description. HUD, and a 1981 tv movie called Bitter Harvest.

This may be a long shot, but you are describing a Danish movie "Flickering Lights". It's from 2000, if my memory serves me.
In this clip, the destructive young man Arne (Mads Mikkelsen) shoots a cow in the face, only to be joined by the farmer to shoot the rest. He gives up the gun as payment for the cow.

Exactly, thank you so much, it's the movie that I was looking for. by the way, it's pretty cool that you found a clip from this exact scene! :)

This is one of the best movies, to ever come out of my homeland IMO. I have seen it countless times, and this scene is one of the most memorable.
Im very surprised to hear you know of it, since i only thought we watched it here, so i didnt really think this was the one you where looking for. Then again, not many movies shows two guys wacking a group of cows :D.

Yes, this is on of all-time-favorites. I posted this question almost desperately! never expected to actually find it! you REALLY made my day :) there is a weekly show on Iran's national TV that reviews best movies of the world and this movie was aired a few years ago, and really impressed me. I think I should have second look on Danish movies :D cheers from Iran!

Haha, im afraid if you start looking for good danish movies, your search will be shorter than you think :P
But there are a few exceptions : http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0418455/?ref_=nv_sr_1
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0180748/?ref_=nv_sr_1
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0342492/?ref_=nv_sr_1
